# Form input type DateTime using Thymeleaf + Spring MVC issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, datetime, thymeleaf

I am struggling to use a Java LocalDateTime scheduledDateTime in a Thymeleaf form and getting it back to save it in the database. I get the following error message :

Bean property 'campaignExecution' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

It is really due to the datetime field. If I remove it from the html form everything works fine and I see the data from the object created in the controller.

My object contains the following along with the getter and setter returning thetype (LocalDateTime) :

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm") 
private LocalDateTime scheduledDateTime;
```

My Controller initialize the value to now()

```
@RequestMapping({ "/campaign1"})
public String requestCampaign1(Model model) {       
CampaignExecution ce = new CampaignExecution();
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
ce.setScheduledDateTime(localDateTime);
model.addAttribute("campaignExecution", ce);
```

And this is the form :

```
    <form id="f" name="f" th:action="@{/campaign1}"
        th:object="${campaignExecution}" method="post">
        <div>
            Schedule a date :
            <input type="datetime-local" th:field=*{campaignExecution.scheduledDateTime} />
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div>Parameters</div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Much easier than I was thinking. For th:field you cannot use multiple object but only the "form object". I was using the full qualifier : object name.property name.